Time complexity using unsigned integers in bit manipulation
Say I am reversing 8 bit unsigned integer in C using bit manipulation.
A quick and novel answer would be to use a loop, be it while() or for().
My assumption is that we take each bit from the integer from bit 0 and placing it in bit 7th position in a temp variable.
example
N = 9 or 00001001b - output is 10010000b,
N = 10 or 00001010b - output is 01010000b
Is this O(N) or O(log N) ?
I initially thought O(N) as loop goes through each bit in the integer.

Is N the number of bits in the field being reversed or is it the number being reversed?

Assuming you're reversing the whole "word" (8 bits or whatever), it's pretty linear. If you're using a temporary bit variable, your loop will have floor(N/2) iterations. If you're using a separate temp "word", you'll have N iterations plus a copy operation.

Re “A quick and novel answer would be to use a loop, be it while() or for()”: Well, no, not really. Bit-reversal is important in FFT implementations, which itself is a hugely important algorithm, so there are academic papers written on bit-reversal. Using a simple loop to swap bits two at a time is neither quick nor novel. For a single byte, a table lookup may be used. For others, search for the papers “Towards an Optimal Bit-Reversal Permutation Program,” “A new superfast bit reversal algorithm,” “A New Fsat Bit-Reversal Permutation Algorithm Based on a Symmetry,” and others.

How could it be O(log N)? As you said, if you loop over the bits it has to access each bit.

@Barmar: It could be O(N) if N is the number to be reversed. Then it has O(log N) significant bits, so reversing them is O(log N). That is why I asked what N is. The question does not state it.

@EricPostpischil Good point. The question specifically says we're reversing an 8-bit number. So we aren't dealing with an arbitrarily large number.

Complexity studies what something costs as a variable is increased. The variable is usually the length of the input or number of values in the data structure.
There's no variable in the scenario you describe. We could examine the complexity of a function that reverses the bits of a string. But you're talking about reversing the bits of a fixed number of bits.
Without a variable, there's only complexity that can be attributed: O(1). Neither time nor space varies based on the input, or at least not by more than a constant amount.

Big-O is an asymptotic analysis. It studies the rate of growth of functions as their variables grows (theoretically to infinity).
Therefore it depends what your N is, and what exactly you are asking.
If you are asking about the specific case of reversing a 8 bit unsigned integer, then since there is no variable here the complexity is constant (O(1)). See the other answer (by @ikegami) for more details about this case.
If you are asking about an unsigned integer with N bits, then the complexity is linear (O(N)) since (as you mentioned) you have to visit each bit.
If you are asking about an unsigned integer of size up to N, then the complexity is logarithmic (O(logN)) since you need an order of logN bits to represent an unsigned integer up to size N (and you have to visit each of the logN bits).
